# Breaking a list into two sublists with Python

Tags: python, list, sublist

Here is the list I want to break down:

```
listA = [[[0, 3], [1, 2]],
 [[0, 2], [1, 3]],
 [[0, 3], [1, 2]],
 [[0, 1], [2, 3]],
 [[0, 2], [1, 3]],
 [[2, 3], [0, 1]],
 [[1, 2], [0, 3]],
 [[2, 3], [0, 1]],
 [[2, 3], [0, 1]],
 [[1, 2], [0, 3]],
 [[1, 2], [0, 3]],
 [[1, 2], [0, 3]],
 [[1, 2], [0, 3]],
 [[2, 3], [0, 1]],
 [[0, 2], [1, 3]],
 [[2, 3], [0, 1]],
 [[2, 3], [0, 1]],
 [[0, 2], [1, 3]],
 [[0, 2], [1, 3]],
 [0, 2],
 [0, 2],
 [0, 2],
 [2, 3],
 [0, 2],
 [0, 2],
 [2, 3],
 [2, 3],
 [2, 3],
 [2, 3],
 [2, 3],
 [[0, 3], [1, 2]],
 [[0, 3], [1, 2]],
 [2, 3],
 [0, 2],
 [0, 2],
 [0, 2],
 [0, 2],
 [1, 2],
 [1, 2]]
```

I'm wondering if I could create two lists, where the first list contains all the sublists of A with their sublists (such as `[[0, 3], [1, 2]], [[2, 3], [0, 1]]`, etc) while the second list contains the sublists of A only have numbers (such as `[1,2]`, `[2,3]`, etc). How can I do that? Thanks for the help:)

Comment: How did you approach this problem? What method have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate throught the list such as:

```
listA = [[[0, 3], [1, 2]], [[0, 2], [1, 3]], [[0, 3], [1, 2]], [[0, 1], [2, 3]], [[0, 2], [1, 3]], [[2, 3], [0, 1]], [[1, 2], [0, 3]], [[2, 3], [0, 1]], [[2, 3], [0, 1]], [[1, 2], [0, 3]], [[1, 2], [0, 3]], [[1, 2], [0, 3]], [[1, 2], [0, 3]], [[2, 3], [0, 1]], [[0, 2], [1, 3]], [[2, 3], [0, 1]], [[2, 3], [0, 1]], [[0, 2], [1, 3]], [[0, 2], [1, 3]], [0, 2], [0, 2], [0, 2], [2, 3], [0, 2], [0, 2], [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [[0, 3], [1, 2]], [[0, 3], [1, 2]], [2, 3], [0, 2], [0, 2], [0, 2], [0, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]

listAux1 = list()
listAux2 = list()

for item in listA:
    if type(item[0]) == list:
        listAux1.append(item)
    else:
        listAux2.append(item)

print(listAux1)
print("------")
print(listAux2)
```

Hope I have answered your question!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this - using `isinstance` to test whether any elements of the sublist are themselves lists.

```
list1 = []
list2 = []

for sublist in listA:
    if any(isinstance(element, list) for element in sublist):
        # contains one or more lists
        list1.append(sublist)
    else:
        # does not contain any lists
        list2.append(sublist)

print(list1)
print(list2)
```

(Another time, please show what you have attempted yourself.)